# Plotting multiple wavelets in a 3D plot in Julia

Tags: julia

I have three variables where x is a range 1:20 of bins, y is a time series from 0s-5s and z are amplitude values of my wavelets (per frequency bin in time). Now, I would like to plot this in a 3D plane, pretty much exactly how it was done in Pan et al. 2018:

[image: Goal]

But I just cannot seem to get it right. I simply don't understand how I would plot these separately. For demonstration purposes, let's assume I have

```
    using Plots;
```

H(n, m) = 0.54 .- 0.46 .* cos.((2 .* pi .* n) ./ (m - 1)); # hamming window

x_axis = (1:20) .* 10; # frequency bins
y_axis = (1:100) .* 1e-3; # time vector in ms
z_axis = H(x_axis, x_axis[end]) .* sin.(2 .* π .* x_axis .* transpose(y_axis)); # amplitude values

display(plot(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis, st=:path3d, ls=:dot));
display(plot(x_axis, y_axis, z_axis, st=:surface, ls=:dot));</pre></code>

But path3d gives me nothing even close to what I want and (obviously) surface also doesn't, as seen below:

[image: Path3D plot]
[image: Surface plot]

So how would I go about getting something similar to the first plot? I'm completely lost here. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the dimensions on the axis arguments are wrong, try something like `plot(repeat(x_axis, 1, length(y_axis)), repeat(y_axis', length(x_axis), 1), z_axis, st=:path3d, ls=:dot)`

Comment: You probably want to take a look at https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-can-i-make-this-plot/31278

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the axis vectors have wrong dimensions. If you extend them to be of the same size as the z-axis array, you get the following (with tweaked ranges for enhanced visuals)

```
H(n, m) = 0.54 .- 0.46 .* cos.((2 .* pi .* n) ./ (m - 1)); # hamming window

x_axis = (1:0.1:20) .* 10; # frequency bins
y_axis = (1:20:100) .* 1e-3; # time vector in ms
z_axis = H(x_axis, x_axis[end]) .* sin.(2 .* π .* x_axis .* transpose(y_axis)); # amplitude values
plot(repeat(x_axis, 1, length(y_axis)), repeat(y_axis', length(x_axis), 1), z_axis, st=:path3d)
```

[image]

Comment: That looks exactly like I'd want it to look, but, unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. All i get is 'ERROR: MethodError: no method matching iterate(::Surface{Array{Float64,2}})
Closest candidates are:
  iterate(::Core.SimpleVector) at essentials.jl:603
  iterate(::Core.SimpleVector, ::Any) at essentials.jl:603
  iterate(::ExponentialBackOff) at error.jl:253'

Comment: Which versions of julia and Plots.jl are you on?

Comment: Julia Version 1.4.1 and [91a5bcdd] Plots v1.3.2